# Formula is is resulting to the left

Tags: excel, match, formula, vlookup

I have a Vlookup with a Match. The Vlookup looks for a country and the match looks for a weight. Each weight for different countries has a different cost.

My formula seems to return the result to the left of what I would expect. So 65kg is returning the cost of 60kg.

This is the code that I have used. I have tried including 1+ in front of D9. I have had False as 0 and I have tried changing the 0's to 1 and -1.

"=VLOOKUP(D8,Express!C2:AU128,MATCH(D9,Express!D3:AU3,0),FALSE)"

Hope this makes sense.

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Match returns the relative position in the range.  so the fact that the third criterion in the VLOOKUP is `1` based not `0` based you need to start the range in the MATCH with the same column as in the VLOOKUP:

Change `Express!D3:AU3` to `Express!C3:AU3`

```
=VLOOKUP(D8,Express!C2:AU128,MATCH(D9,Express!C3:AU3,0),FALSE)
```

Comment: Doesn't `MATCH` only work on one-dimensional datasets?

Comment: @M.Schalk it is only a one dimensional.  it is only on row 3

Answer (score 1):

Try this formula:

```
=VLOOKUP(D8,Express!C2:AU128,MATCH(D9,Express!D3:AU3,0)+1,FALSE)
```